# CIFS mount fails when read is interrupted

Tags: centos, cifs

I have a functioning CIFS mount from CentOS 6.4, 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64, to a Windows file server.  If I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> while doing some IO intensive (like `fgrep -r`), then the mount (and all other mounts to the same file server) becomes unusable until I either reboot or forcibly unmount and remount.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is as reported here:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-cifs/msg07576.html

What I don't know, and don't know how to figure out, is whether the fix will ever work its way into CentOS 6.4.

From what I can tell, the corresponding source code on centOS is in `fs/cifs/transport.c`, line 492.

And indeed, building the cifs kernel module with "--server->sequence_number;" before that line does seem to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would compile this patch and confirm that it fixes my issue first before worrying about if it will get into CentOS upstream. It should be pretty easy to take the source RPM (SRPM) version of the package providing CIFS, apply the patch, recompile, and upgrade to it.

Comment: I wasn't looking forward to compiling the kernel, but this turned out to be easier than I thought, and verifies that the change does fix the problem.

Comment: @jjanes - glad that solved your problem, please mark this answer as accepted so that others know your issue's been resolved.